# How to enable Server service in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, services

This is a laptop machine provided by the enterprise I work in, it has installed some VPN and monitoring software. Server service is not listed in services manager and Docker refuses to install with the following message:

`Docker Desktop requires the Server service to be enabled`

By default employees can't install software in this machines, but as developer one can request administrative permissions as I did. I'm almost sure that they disabled the service but I can't figure out why.

How can I install or enable it?

Comment: what's the output if you run `sc query lanmanserver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the needed privilege, try exporting the registry key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver]` on another Windows 10 machine, and import the resulting `.reg` file on your enterprise laptop.

If that doesn't work, copy `C:\Windows\System32\srvsvc.dll` from the other machine and try again.

Sources: [Windows 7 'Server' services are missing ... ?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/ab9bb66d-b9a5-4e88-8f85-fdbd77416bdd/windows-7-server-services-are-missing-)

Comment: copying .reg from another machine worked! Services manager shows Server service as *automatic in execution* but dont let me stop or restart the service, neither edit it, but anyways, I have running the service I wanted, thanks!